# How to send the selected option from mysql to another page using ajax

Tags: php, html, forms

this is my code.

```
...
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-8">      
            <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" name="video_name" id="video_name">
                    <select name="video_format">
                        <option value="">Choose Video format</option>
                        <?php require 'connection.php';
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM videofmt";
                        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                <option value="<?php echo $row["video_format"]?>"><?php echo $row["video_format"];?>
<?php }} ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Upload File" name="upload"
                           onclick="uploadFileHandler()">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function _(abc) {
    return document.getElementById(abc);
}
function uploadFileHandler() {
    document.getElementById('progressDiv').style.display='block';
    var file = _("video_name").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("video_name", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event) {
    var loaded = new Number((event.loaded / 1048576));//Make loaded a "number" and divide bytes to get Megabytes
    var total = new Number((event.total / 1048576));//Make total file size a "number" and divide bytes to get Megabytes
    _("uploaded_progress").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + loaded.toPrecision(5) + " Megabytes of " + total.toPrecision(5);//String output
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;//Get percentage of upload progress
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);//Round value to solid
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded";//String output
}
function completeHandler(event) {
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;//Build and show response text
    _("progressBar").value = 0;//Set progress bar to 0
    document.getElementById('progressDiv').style.display = 'none';//Hide progress bar
}
function errorHandler(event) {
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";//Switch status to upload failed
}
function abortHandler(event) {
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";//Switch status to aborted
}
</script>
</body>
...
```

I have a code that select rows from mysql for option selection. Ajax could not identify my selected value from the drop down list. I tried to echo the selected value $row["video_format"] but this does not work but echo only the last row from mysql.

The problem is how to show or send the particular selected option from the dropdown list from the while loop.

Comment: The PHP isn't correct. You're missing `?>` before `<option value="`

Comment: Is that a copying error? If not, you should be getting PHP syntax errors.

Comment: it is copying error.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: You want to send a video with its format to the server, but the while sending the video the format isn't send?

Comment: yes, the selected format is not sending but the video file name in the input tag is sending

Comment: you forgot to add a `format = _("video_format"); formdata.append("video_format", format);`, because otherwise it wont be send to the server in any case, because it is not in the formdata object. EDIT: made a mistake: "video_name" should be something different like "video_format"

Comment: ok I will add it and confirm

Comment: The server still could not see any selected format I choose from the list. It is showing undefined variable. Therefore I echo $row["video_format"]; to see if my selected value is showing but it is only show the last added format in mysql without the one I select from the drop down.

Comment: Do you really need a menu for the video format? PHP has a built-in function to determine the format of a video file.

Comment: Aren't you going to fix that copying error? How did that even happen? You can't possibly have retyped this whole thing, did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found multiple issues:

1. you are missing closing option tags (`</option>`), so every option just gets opened; also add the `video_format` as id so you can use it in javascript
2. as said in the comments, you are missing the input in the `formdata` object

Do the following:

```php
<!-- ... -->
<select name="video_format" id="video_format">
    <option value="">Choose Video format</option>
    <?php
    require 'connection.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM videofmt";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["video_format"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["video_format"]; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
<!-- ... -->
```

```js
function uploadFileHandler() {
    // ...
    var file = _("video_name").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("video_name", file);
    var format = _("video_format").value;
    formdata.append("video_format", format);
    // ...
}
```

add an closing tag and add the input to the formdata.

### TIPP:

There is also a way to easily add input fields to the `formdata` object

```js
formdata = new FormData(
    document.getElementById("upload_form")
);
```

Comment: Closing `</option>` tags are actually optional. Another `<option>` automatically closes the previous one.

Comment: In general yes, but it makes readability and the structure of the code worse then it should. I know it isn't XHTML, but in XHTML for example you can't do this.

Comment: It is not necessary to repeat an option's text as its `value` attribute all form submission and javascript behaviors will still be the same. Also, a mysqli result set object can be unconditionally passed to a `foreach()` for simpler fetching syntax. `foreach (mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM videofmt") as $row) { ?> <?php printf('<option>%s</option>', $row["video_format"]); ?> <?php } ?>`